# Find value of K in matrix

Tags: matrices

Find the value of "k" in the equation:

$k\left(\begin{array}{cc}3 & -1 \\ 5 & -4\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}-3/4 & 1/4 \\ -5/4 & 1\end{array}\right)$

do I multiply $3 * (-3/4)$ then $(-1) * 1/4$ then $5 *(-5/4)$ and $(-4) * 1$ ?

Comment: Need to reformat the matrices.  I would, but I'm brand new here and don't know how.

Comment: The technique provided in my answer to your other question http://math.stackexchange.com/a/173309/31475 should point you in the right direction.

Comment: It's non-singular, so you can also do this :) $$ k = \left(\begin{array}{cc}-3/4 & 1/4 \\ -5/4 & 1\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{cc}3 & -1 \\ 5 & -4\end{array}\right)^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't multiply the entries of the matrices. Remember how you multiply a matrix by a scalar:

$$\alpha\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a &b\\
c& d
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\alpha a& \alpha b\\
\alpha c & \alpha d
\end{array}\right)$$
that is, you multiply *each* entry by the scalar.

So here, you are looking to see if you can find a single number $k$ such that
$$\left(\begin{array}{rr}
k\cdot 3 & k\cdot (-1)\\
k\cdot 5 & k\cdot (-4)
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{rr}
-\frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{4}\\
-\frac{5}{4} & 1
\end{array}\right).$$
In other words, you are trying to solve **four** equations simultaneously:
$$\begin{align*}
3k &= -\frac{3}{4}\\
-k &= \frac{1}{4}\\
5k &=-\frac{5}{4}\\
-4k &= 1
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since it's just a case of scalar multiplication, you can do this:

$$3k = \frac{-3}{4} \tag{1}$$
$$-k = \frac{1}{4} \tag{2}$$
$$5k = \frac{-5}{4} \tag{3}$$
$$-4k = 1 \tag{4}$$

Solving any one of those four equations will get you the value of $k$, in this case, $-\frac{1}{4}.$